# How to test controller/gamepad implementation on Android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-tv, gamepad

I need to implement a controller/gamepad support for my mobile game. I'm trying to make my game work on Android TV. However, I noticed, there is no controller/gamepad mocking on Android TV's emulator. How can I test it and make sure everything works before actually shipping?

Comment: Can you explain more with what you want with gamepad or dpad ?

Comment: @jaydroider I want to make sure gamepad support implementation works. Android emulator seems to have no gamepad testing capabilities. What could you suggest?

Comment: As i know more about using **D-pad** so i don't have more idea about gamepad as i have only worked with **D-pad** in my tv app.

Comment: Try putting some actions in your XML layout for gamepad.